# Shorten this code while fixing a major bug

Tags: code-golf

I found the code below today after much hair pulling. Shorten it down (code golf) and fix the bug that I found (bonus).

```c
#define LN_SOME_TEXT_FIELD 256

void GetSomeText(LPTSTR text)
{
    TCHAR       buf[LN_SOME_TEXT_FIELD + 1];
    short       i;
    LPTSTR      curChar;

    curChar = text;
    i = 0;
    while (*curChar != NULL) {
        if (*curChar != '&') {
            buf[i] = *curChar;
            i++;
        }
        curChar++;
    }
    buf[i] = NULL;
    SomeOtherUIFunction(buf);
}
```

**EDIT** 
Added a tail call, this is what the real function does, sorry for not including it earlier.

Comment: Hard to tell bugs from features without a spec

Comment: I'm guessing there is even a deeper bug here: Is this code meant to "unescape" a string, for some escaping mechanism?

Comment: @MtnViewMark, my guess is that it's removing the & which is used in Windows to indicate the shortcut key of a widget

Comment: @Peter, ah yes, the type names should have clued me in!

Comment: Is this code golf or darn it I'll post this as code golf and claim the credit at work. ¬¬ (shifty eyes)

Comment: @mbomb why bump this, lmao

Comment: @Flp.Tkc Because it's unclear what they're asking.

Comment: @mbomb007 but it was posted in 2011, buried under all challenges, why bring it to the top?

Comment: @Flp.Tkc To close it. We do that all the time. If we find an old question that'd not on topic, you close it.

Comment: Old questions can still be answered, so if one should be closed, it shouldn't be overlooked simply because it's old.

Comment: Similarly, if we find old answers that were not deleted, but are invalid or joke answers or don't meet the specs, then we delete them.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you didn't fix the bug already?  I don't see a flaw in the logic, but I do see a few obvious problems:

- <strike>The output buffer is never returned, so this function is a no-op.</strike> The post was changed so the `buf` is used now.
- The output buffer has a fixed-width.  This is fine, as long as the input's length does not exceed LN_SOME_TEXT_FIELD.
- Using `NULL` instead of `'\0'`.  `NULL` expands to `((void*) 0)`, meaning it's a pointer.  It should not be used to refer to the null character.

Anyway, here is a nicer (in my opinion) version of the code above:

```
void GetSomeText(const char *in, char *out)
{
    for (; *in != '\0'; in++) {
        if (*in != '&')
            *out++ = *in;
    }
    *out = '\0';
}
```

Comment: this one also fixes the possible `i` overflowing error. (well, actually, it'll go out of bounds before that...but still...)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 13 characters

```
filter(/='&')
```

or, not golf'd:

```
getSomeText :: String -> String
getSomeText = filter (/='&')
```

But, I'm guessing that this isn't the desired function, but probably something that unescapes. If so, then the function is `g`, 36 characters:

```
g('&':a:z)=a:g z;g(a:z)=a:g z;g _=[]
```

or, not golf'd:

```
getSomeText :: String -> String
getSomeText ('&':a:as) = a : getSomeString as
getSomeText (    a:as) = a : getSomeString as
getSomeText []         = []
```

Seriously, *this* is exactly [why functional programming matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/Papers/whyfp.pdf). "Turn on, tune in, [learn Haskell!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)"

Answer (score 4):

#### Perl, 5 chars

```
s/&//
```

Or

```
sub GetSomeText{$@[0]~=s/&//}
```

if you insist on wrapping something so trivial in a subroutine.